# RXJS Switchmap - is it possible on value

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Is there a way to switchMap on a particular value ?

```
 jobsFilter(value) {
    console.log(value);
   value.switchMap(value => this.http.get(`http://localhost:55250/api/search/jobs/${value}`))
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: What is the type of value? Is it an Observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your simply value inside an Observable "Everything is a Stream"

```
Observable.of(yourValue).switchMap(yourSwitchMapFunction)
```

@pixelbits the constructor of a Subject doesn't have any parameter, and less a value, since the productor of values of the Subject are outside the stream, if you want to use a Subject you need to do something like this:

```
const mySubject = new Subject<string>();
mySubject.switchMap(mySwitchMapFunction);

mySubject.next(myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
 this.o = new Subject<string>(value);
 this.o2 = o.switchMap(t=> this.http.get(`http://localhost:55250/api/search/jobs/${value}`))
    .map(res=>res.json());
```

Setup your subscribers:

```
 this.o2.subscribe(...);
```

To Trigger:

```
jobsFilter(value) {
    this.o.next(value);
}
```